# SQL How do I script a index to a sproc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, indexing

Does anyone know how to script an index. If I have 2 indexes and I want to script them to a sproc, how do I do this, like how do I seperate each of the indexes and copy them into a stored procedure?

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [index1]    Script Date: 03/26/2014 20:31:47 ******/
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [index1] ON [dbo].[EmployeeTbl] 
(
[ID] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How do I script, this, and another index into a sproc and save it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'GO' keywords separate the sql script into discrete operations that are executed sequentially. Whilst it's important for the index creation to happen against the right database (per the 'USE' command), this will tend to happen correctly for you once you've opened you SqlConnection.

So the important stuff to put on your SqlCommand is everything between the 'GO' statements (and don't include these).

You can add a second CREATE INDEX to your first without needing a 'GO' in between. A newline will generally suffice. (A semi-colon will force the two to be recognised as two separate CREATE commands if you're paranoid.)

Comment: Ok, so after the 2nd GO I should paste the other index underneath it and save the proc? e.g.  `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX GO `

Answer (score 1):

You could always use dynamic SQL

Create a string that contains the script that will Create the Index:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CreateIndex
AS

  DECLARE @index_script NVARCHAR(2000)

  SET @index_script = 'CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [index1] ON [dbo].[EmployeeTbl] 
  (
  [ID] ASC
  )
  WITH (PAD_INDEX  = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]'

  EXEC(@index_script)
```